# Keras report wrong accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm training a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) in Keras.

My log reports that both networks (discriminator and combined model) reached 100% accuracy. That indicates that something is wrong.

I try running inference and see that the discriminator is indeed 100% accurate, but the generator generates only noise, and wasn't fooling the discriminator at all.

My question: why did Keras report my combined model's accuracy as 100%?

Code:

```python
generator = create_generator(input_shape=(374,))
in_vector = Input(shape=(374,))
fake_images = generator(in_vector)

discriminator = create_discriminator()
disc_optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4)
discriminator.compile(optimizer=disc_optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

discriminator.trainable = False
for l in discriminator.layers:
    l.trainable = False

gan_output = discriminator(fake_images)
gan = Model(in_vector, gan_output)
gan_optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5)
gan.compile(optimizer=gan_optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f'data/logs/gawwn/{start_time}')
tensorboard.set_model(gan)

d_train_logs = ['train_discriminator_loss',
                'train_discriminator_accuracy']
g_train_logs = ['train_generator_loss',
                'train_generator_accuracy']
val_logs = ['val_discriminator_loss',
            'val_discriminator_accuracy',
            'val_generator_loss',
            'val_generator_accuracy']

d_train_step, g_train_step, val_step = 0, 0, 0

valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

noise_sigma = 0.00
noise_decay = 0.95

for epoch in range(1, 1 + epochs):
    d_loss = [1]
    while d_loss[0] > d_loss_thres:
        for i, (x_vectors, x_images, y) in enumerate(train_loader.load_batch(batch_size)):
            # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            # Generate a batch of new images
            gen_imgs = generator.predict(x_vectors)

            # Train the discriminator
            data = np.concatenate([y, gen_imgs], axis=0)
            labels = np.concatenate([valid[:len(y)], fake[:len(y)]])
            train_batch = list(zip(data, labels))
            np.random.shuffle(train_batch)
            data, labels = zip(*train_batch)
            data, labels = np.array(data), np.array(labels)
            d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(data, labels)

#             d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(y, valid[:len(y)])
#             d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake[:len(y)])
#             d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
            write_log(tensorboard, d_train_logs, d_loss, d_train_step)
            d_train_step += 1
            time_elaped = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
            print(f'D step {d_train_step}: loss={d_loss[0]}; acc={d_loss[1]}; time={time_elaped}')

    g_loss = [1]
    while g_loss[0] > g_loss_thres:
        for i, (x_vectors, x_images, y) in enumerate(train_loader.load_batch(batch_size)):
            # ---------------------
            #  Train Generator
            # ---------------------

            # Train the generator (to have the discriminator label samples as valid)
            g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(x_vectors, valid[:len(y)])

            # Plot the progress
            write_log(tensorboard, g_train_logs, g_loss, g_train_step)
            g_train_step += 1

            time_elaped = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
            print(f'G step {g_train_step}: loss={g_loss[0]}; acc={g_loss[1]}; time={time_elaped}')

    # If at save interval => save generated image samples
    if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
        d_losses = []
        g_losses = []
        for x_vectors, x_images, y in val_loader.load_batch(batch_size):
            gen_imgs = generator.predict(x_vectors)
            d_loss_real = discriminator.test_on_batch(y, valid[:len(y)])
            d_loss_fake = discriminator.test_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake[:len(y)])
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
            d_losses.append(d_loss)

            g_loss = gan.test_on_batch(x_vectors, valid[:len(y)])
            g_losses.append(g_loss)

        d_loss = np.average(d_losses, axis=0)
        g_loss = np.average(g_losses, axis=0)
        write_log(tensorboard, val_logs, [d_loss[0], d_loss[1], g_loss[0], g_loss[1]], val_step)
        val_step += 1
        sample_images(val_loader, generator, epoch)
        save_model(generator, epoch, 'generator')
        save_model(discriminator, epoch, 'discriminator')
```

Results of the last few steps:

```python
D step 349: loss=0.09932675957679749; acc=1.0; time=0:05:58.468997
D step 350: loss=0.10563915222883224; acc=0.9900000095367432; time=0:05:59.088657
D step 351: loss=0.09658461064100266; acc=1.0; time=0:05:59.533442
G step 214: loss=0.167491614818573; acc=0.9800000190734863; time=0:06:00.196747
G step 215: loss=0.13409791886806488; acc=1.0; time=0:06:00.891946
G step 216: loss=0.1523411124944687; acc=0.9722222089767456; time=0:06:01.402974
D step 352: loss=0.10553492605686188; acc=0.9900000095367432; time=0:06:02.015083
D step 353: loss=0.10318870842456818; acc=0.9900000095367432; time=0:06:02.654599
D step 354: loss=0.07871382683515549; acc=1.0; time=0:06:03.131933
G step 217: loss=0.1493617743253708; acc=0.9800000190734863; time=0:06:03.827815
G step 218: loss=0.12147567421197891; acc=0.9599999785423279; time=0:06:04.537494
G step 219: loss=0.17327196896076202; acc=1.0; time=0:06:05.099841
D step 355: loss=0.10441411286592484; acc=0.9900000095367432; time=0:06:05.768096
D step 356: loss=0.09612423181533813; acc=1.0; time=0:06:06.451947
D step 357: loss=0.1072489321231842; acc=0.9861111044883728; time=0:06:06.937882
```

Inference:

```python
>>> np.reshape(discriminator.predict(ground_truth), (5, 10))

array([[0.5296475 , 0.52787906, 0.5270807 , 0.5260455 , 0.528732  ,
        0.52820367, 0.53157693, 0.52730876, 0.5244186 , 0.52673554],
       [0.5229454 , 0.5239704 , 0.53051734, 0.52862865, 0.52718925,
        0.52680767, 0.52621156, 0.5308223 , 0.52489233, 0.5297055 ],
       [0.53033316, 0.5260847 , 0.5300899 , 0.52788675, 0.529595  ,
        0.52183014, 0.5321261 , 0.5251559 , 0.52876014, 0.52384466],
       [0.528658  , 0.52737784, 0.53003156, 0.52685475, 0.53047454,
        0.52759105, 0.52710444, 0.52546424, 0.52709824, 0.52520245],
       [0.5283209 , 0.52810913, 0.52451426, 0.5196351 , 0.5299184 ,
        0.5274567 , 0.52686375, 0.5269972 , 0.5248108 , 0.5263274 ]],
      dtype=float32)

>>> np.reshape(gan.predict(input_vector), (5, 10))

array([[0.4719111 , 0.47217596, 0.47209665, 0.47233126, 0.4741753 ,
        0.4712048 , 0.4721919 , 0.47193947, 0.47010162, 0.47092766],
       [0.47291884, 0.47334394, 0.4714141 , 0.46976995, 0.47092718,
        0.47233835, 0.47164065, 0.47276756, 0.47107005, 0.47187868],
       [0.47153524, 0.47157907, 0.4706026 , 0.47128928, 0.47320494,
        0.47089615, 0.47108623, 0.47432283, 0.47186196, 0.47404772],
       [0.47164053, 0.47348404, 0.4701542 , 0.4741918 , 0.4702833 ,
        0.47303212, 0.4726331 , 0.47118646, 0.47191456, 0.47318774],
       [0.47043982, 0.47027725, 0.47308347, 0.47376725, 0.4733549 ,
        0.47157207, 0.47205287, 0.47177386, 0.47119975, 0.4707804 ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, and it only happens if I use `train_on_batch()`. Tried using my own accuracy implementation, but still reported values do not match the actual predictions that were made.

Answer (score -1):

Notice `gan = Model(in_vector, gan_output)`, so your model is defined as all the layers from the input vector to the output of the discriminator, including generator in the middle. So when you call

`gan.compile(optimizer=gan_optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`, it automatically uses output from discriminator to determine accuracy. So in order to obtain generators accuracy, you can use a callback and manually calculate 'accuracy' however that may be defined for your generator (plus generators don't have a typical metric for accuracy when you think about it, what are you going to compare it to?). **Also, if your generator is producing random noise, that doesnt mean the accuracy should be 0, and since you are only using accuracy of discriminator and it is successfully identifying the output to not belong to the underlying distribution, the accuracy remains 100 percent (which is easy as the output of generator is random noise) . In short, high accuracy of discriminator doesn't imply that generator successfully fooled the discriminator or not. In fact, when the accuracy of discriminator is close to 50 percent, it would mean that generator does model the input data well and discriminator cannot differentiate between the two and is making random guesses. Thus what you are seeing is expected behavior**

Comment: I think you misunderstood my situation.

During training, I force the labels of gan (the combined model) to be 1 (real):
`g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(x_vectors, valid[:len(y)])`

Look at the inference output of gan, I see that all predictions are less than 0.5, meaning the model predicts 0 for all generated images. In summary: Correct label should be 1, but all predictions are 0. So why does it report accuracy as 100%?